# Appending to a text file in C

Tags: c

Here's the function. I run the program but the the file doesn't change.

```
void add (char *name, int stock, int limit, float cost) {
    FILE *afp = fopen("./inventory.csv","a+");
    fprintf(afp,"%s,%d,%d,%f\n",name,stock,limit,cost);
    fclose(afp);
}
```

Edit: Oops, I just didn't call the function.

Comment: Have you checked if `afp==NULL`?

Comment: Do you actually call the above function in your program?

Comment: what did the debugger say

Comment: @KristerAndersson, this really looks a better question :))) "Do you actually call the above function in your program? "

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking to see if your file exists or has opened correctly. Check to see if *afp points to NULL. Lastly check to see if your parameters have values to be appended.

Comment: It does not matter whether the parameters have values or not. The question says that the file doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void add( char* name, int stock, int limit, float cost )
{
  FILE *afp;
  errno_t err = fopen_s( &afp, "./inventory.csv", "a+" );
  if( !err )
  {
    fprintf( afp, "%s,%d,%d,%f\n", name, stock, limit, cost );
    fclose( afp );
  }
}

int main()
{
  add( "book", 12, 10, 15.2 );

  return 0;
}
```

> The file doesn't change?

This is maybe because you are not allowed to open in. I mean that you do not haave the required rights for reading and appending to that file.

> Doesn't the file exist?

This doesn't matter. As it is said on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx) reference, if you open a file in `read-and-append` mode, the file is created if it doesn't exist.

*Opens for reading and appending. The appending operation includes the removal of the EOF marker before new data is written to the file and the EOF marker is restored after writing is complete. Creates the file if it doesn't exist.*